# Has any Asura or Rakshasa destroyed a city with an Astra, like the Brahmastra?

Tags: weapon, brahmastra

It is recorded in the Puranas and Itihasas that Krishna and Shiva destroyed some cities, like Kashi and Tripura respectively, with astras and other celestial weapons.

My question is, has any Asura (Daitya or Danava) or Rakshasa destroyed a city with an Astra, like the Brahmastra?

Note, that I'm talking about complete obliteration of a city using a celestial weapon, and not mere sacking, pillaging, and burning of a city, which the Asuras and Rakshasas have done countless times.

Comment: In Ramayana, it was stated that Indrajit eliminated 66 crores of Vanaras on a Single day.   So it might be possible.  Further,celestial weapons can be used according to the wish of the user.  Indrajit used Brahmastra also to tie Sri Hanuman. So destruction of a city may not be difficult@Ikshvaku.